# Disabling WebBrowser ActiveX Warning

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

I am currently running a WebBrowser in WPF, that WebBrowser is going to play a .SWF file. Every time the program debugs it asks for an Active X Agreement before running the file.
I am not using HTML but set the Source in the WebBrowser itself: (EDIT : I no longer set the source in the WebBrowser)

```
<WebBrowser Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="wbMain" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800"/>
```

I have searched a few hours for a suitable solution but did not manage to find the way to disable that warning. Am I missing anything ? Must I use HTML to disable the warning? and how to do so?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Okay, I've managed to fit my needs using HTML, I've placed an HTML called 1.Html in the .exe directory:
The first line makes the warning dissapear.

```
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<object width="800" height="600">
<param name="SRC" value="Ninja dance.swf">
<embed src="Ninja dance.swf" width="800" height="600">
</embed>
</object>
</html>
```

And then at the program :

```
webBrowserName.Navigate(new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/1.html"));
```

:)